# If the terminal is malicious, is paying with NFC still safe?

Tags: credit-card, nfc

Paying with credit card's NFC. I know about tokenization and all that, but does that actually protect my card against theft when the terminal is malicious?

Answer (score 4):

No. That terminal can execute **pre-play attack** on the card. The card authorizes a payment request by issuing a signed **Dynamic Application Data**. This step is called **Transaction Authorization**. The dynamic application data is only valid for the **Unpredictable Number** generated by the terminal for the current payment request. That means a terminal will reject the response from the card if the unpredictable number returned in response is different from what terminal sent in the request which happens when someone is trying to reuse the card response from a past transaction.

A malicious terminal however will trick the card to issue multiple transaction authorization for future payment requests. To the person on the counter and to the cardholder, it will appear as if the terminal is not detecting the card. Assuming the lack of contact, the cardholder will tap multiple times and for each tap, the terminal will issue a new payment request and store the unused transaction authorization. Then it can allow the very first transaction authorization for processing to clear the suspicion while keeping the unused transactions for the attacker to use after the customer leaves.

The unused transaction authorizations cannot be used on other legitimate terminals because their unpredictable number will be different.